# capistrano and ec2 and github - unable to deploy

Tags: github, ruby-on-rails-3.2, capistrano

I am trying to deploy my first webapp to EC2 using capistrano and the repo is on github. But I am facing issues with "cap deploy:cold". The deploy.rb is pasted below. Following are the steps I followed.

1) Logged into ec2 instance using ssh from my local machine. Generated keys using ssh-keygen without any passphrase.

2) Took the contents of id_rsa.pub and copied to the github repo settings deploy keys.

3) Then from my local machine, ran "cap deploy:cold". I get the following error

user1@laptop:~/MyExample$ cap deploy:cold
  * 2013-03-01 19:08:06 executing `deploy:cold'

  * 2013-03-01 19:08:06 executing`deploy:update'
 ** transaction: start
  * 2013-03-01 19:08:06 executing `deploy:update_code'
    updating the cached checkout on all servers
    executing locally: "git ls-remote git@github.com:user1/MyExample.git HEAD"
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
  * executing "rm -rf /var/www/MyExample.com/releases/20130301133835; true"
    servers: ["181.73.124.219"]
    [181.73.124.219] executing command
    command finished in 1186ms

---

set :application, "MyExample.com"
set :scm, "git"
set :repository,  "git@github.com:thisuser/example.git"

default_run_options[:pty] = true

set :user, 'ubuntu'
set :use_sudo, true
set :deploy_to, "/var/www/#{application}"
set :deploy_via, :remote_cache

role :web, "181.73.124.219"
role :app, "181.73.124.219"
role :db,  "181.73.124.219", :primary => true

after "deploy", "deploy:bundle_gems"
after "deploy:bundle_gems", "deploy:restart"

namespace :deploy do
  task :bundle_gems do
    run "cd #{deploy_to}/current && bundle install vandor/gems"
  end
  task :start do ; end
  task :stop do ; end
  task :restart, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do
    run "#{try_sudo} touch #{File.join(current_path,'tmp','restart.txt')}"
  end
end

What am I missing here? Also any pointers to a URL/blog that can provide detailed steps would help.

Thanks.

Comment: I believe this seems to be an issue with the keys, but not sure how to fix it. Any help appreciated.

Comment: some more updates. I checked against help provided at https://help.github.com/articles/error-permission-denied-publickey. Everything is fine and even verified that the public key attached to github account is also same.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working. As seen in the log,
**executing locally: "git ls-remote git@github.com:user1/MyExample.git HEAD"**

the capistrano is trying to run the above command local machine and not on the server. Running the above command on the terminal also returned the same error - Permission denied (Public Key).

So I had to copy the generated id_rsa and id_rsa.pub from the deploy server to the local machine. And after copying, add it to the ssk keys being used by running "ssh-add /path/to/keys".

After adding those keys, I was able to move ahead.